# Singleton Pattern in Unity removing duplicate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

GameManager.cs

```cs
private void Awake()
    {
        //check if instance is null, if null then create 
        if (instance == null) {
            //refers to the GameManager class
            instance = this;
            //dont destroy gamemanger game object when loading new scene
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        } else {

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Why is Destroy(gameObject) necessary with a singleton pattern? Why would a second instance be created in the first place?

Comment: If you loaded a new scene with that script in it there would be a second instance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be created by different reasons. For example:

- Loading the scene again in case of an object with this script is in the scene
- Instantiating an object with this script attached
- Perhaps some attempt to manually add a component to an object (this is completely legal to call `gameObject.AddComponent<MyAwesomeType>()`)

So as you cannot be sure that object will not be duplicated, you have to be sure that only the first created instance stays alive